# Why Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields when using sub query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to use this query but I get this error:

> **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

I think the problem is the sub-query, because if I use only:

```
SELECT id_location_home FROM location_home WHERE location_home.location = ?
```

**The error disappears.**

*Problem*

```
($sql = $db -> prepare("
    UPDATE `database_charts`.`single_user` 
    SET `location_home_id_location_home` = (
    SELECT id_location_home FROM location_home 
    WHERE location_home.location = ?)"
));
$sql -> bind_param('s', $location); // error here

$sql -> execute();
```

How I can solve this? Is possible change this query to a join? Probably solve the issue.

Comment: "tion = ?;)" - Should that semicolon be in there?

Comment: Why is that extra `;` at the end of the sub-query there?

Comment: the problem is not the ;. i will remove.

Comment: How about removing the parenthesis that wrap lines 1-6?

Comment: Echo out the query and past it directly into mysql and see if it works... 
                echo "UPDATE `database_charts`.`single_user` 
                SET `location_home_id_location_home` = (
                SELECT id_location_home FROM location_home 
                WHERE location_home.location = $location)"

Comment: the query works if i change the ? to the city, like london

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
UPDATE `database_charts`.`single_user` 
SET `location_home_id_location_home` = location_home.id_location_home
FROM location_home 
WHERE location_home.location = ?
```

Also, that query of yours seems fishy. You really want to update every single row in single_user?